# In tmux, how to set shortcut for 'copy mode'?

Tags: tmux

I am using `tmux` and I found that entering *copy mode* is really tedious:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

while <kbd>[</kbd> is not on the *home row*.

I am thinking about creating a shortcut for it, e.g. <kbd>F4</kbd>, so I can reach it with one stroke of my left index finger.

Do you know how to create a shortcut like this?

thx

Answer (score 6):

this is actually much simpler than what I had thought

with the help from EchoMike444

add the following line into you .tmux.conf

```
bind-key -n F4 copy-mode
```

Comment: What if I want the shortcut to enter copy-mode then start a search?
I tried:

`bind-key -n F1 copy-mode -X search-reverse`

But that didnt work.

Answer (score 5):

In case you land here because you want to remap copy-mode to something else. Here is an example of mapping it to [CTRL+ALT+C](https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-alt-c):

```
# map copy mode to ctrl+alt+c
bind-key -n 'C-M-c' copy-mode
```

Might be of interest, the complete setup to copy paste in tmux updated from 
rushiagr.com [everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting](https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/)

```
bind P paste-buffer
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
# Also copy to system clipboard
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
# map copy mode to ctrl+alt+c
bind-key -n 'C-M-c' copy-mode
```

Answer (score 0):

from man **tmux**

```
Key bindings may be changed with the bind-key and unbind-key commands.
```

extract of .tmux.conf

```
set-option -g prefix C-t
unbind-key C-b
bind-key C-t send-prefix
```

Comment: I know how to change it from Ctrl-a [ to Ctrl-a v, but i don't want to have control prefix here, I want one single stroke, F4