# How can I configure tmux's copy-mode-vi so that the m key moves to the end of line (equivalent to $)

Tags: tmux

The QA [how to set shortcut for 'copy mode'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450184/in-tmux-how-to-set-shortcut-for-copy-mode) explains how to set a shortcut to tmux copy mode. My question is different, I want to change a shortcut within copy mode, in particular `copy-mode-vi`. This is part of my `~/.tmux.conf` where I have set up copy mode:

```
# Copy paste in tmux based on
# https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/
bind P paste-buffer
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
# Also copy to system clipboard
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
# map copy mode to ctrl+alt+c
bind-key -n 'C-M-c' copy-mode
# map paste buffer to ctrl+alt+v
bind-key -n 'C-M-v' paste-buffer
```

I have my vim normal mode `$` mapped to the `m` key (I use an azerty keyboard). How can I configure tmux's `copy-mode-vi` in a similar way so that the `m` moves to the end of line (i.e. `$`).

Answer (score 0):

You config already seems to have some good examples. Try

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi m send-keys -X end-of-line
```